# nginx use next rule after ip filter

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a pretty typical Wordpress install behind nginx where I have rules defined like:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Now, I want to IP restrict the admin and login pages, and I add the following before the above pasted code:

```
    location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
            allow $myip;
            deny all;
    }
```

This makes it so I can access wp-admin/ and wp-login.php only with the specified IP address, but it ends up downloading the .php files instead of proxying them to PHP then returning the result. How can I change the above rule to say just process the rest of the rules (i.e. fall into the "location /" or "location ~ .php" blocks?

Comment: Duplicated http://serverfault.com/questions/254430/nginx-block-ip-based-on-uri-in-one-location